# Cursor Based Pagination Across Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, pagination

I have 3 tables that are accessed as individual feeds and also a group feed.

For individual feeds, I can implement cursor-based pagination based on each row's unique id.

How would I implement cursor-based pagination for the group feed, which basically combines all 3 tables into 1 feed?

Each table has unique ids and a timestamp for when it was created (although this is not unique).

I've considered using the timestamp as some sort of pointer, for example, results after a particular timestamp, but this could lead to missing results, as if you requested 10 rows, after a timestamp, and these rows all had the same timestamp, as did another 20 rows, when you perform a subsequent request, you will miss those following 20 rows.

How can this problem be tackled?

Answer (score 2):

### Window functions.

MySQL 8.0 introduced support for standard SQL window functions. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ..., ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rownum
  FROM <multiple tables joined>
) AS t
WHERE rownum BETWEEN ? and ?
```

No need for `LIMIT`. You just use parameters to select the range of rows corresponding to the current "page" you want to view.

If you answer "but I haven't upgraded to MySQL 8.0 yet," then I would say now you have a good reason to upgrade.